# How to increase iOS live activities presentation lifetime?

Tags: swift, widget

How to increase live activities presentation lifetime?
As I know, Live Activity remains on the Lock Screen for a maximum of twelve hours.

Answer (score 2):

You can't go against the system limitations and have a Live Activity that last more than 12 hours (note that the last 4 hours, you activity cannot be updated anymore).

One thing you can do when the user open your app is to cancel the soon-to-be-expired Activity and start a new one. It will transparent for the user.

Keep in mind that doing so might be an issue with the app review since you are using Live Activity outside of the scope fixed by Apple.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the 12-hour maximum is exclusive only to the Lock Screen, whereas the lifetime on the Dynamic Island is limited to only 8 hours.